# Can't resume "wget --mirror" with --no-clobber (-c -F -B unhelpful)

Tags: wget

I started a wget mirror with "wget --mirror [sitename]", and it was 
working fine, but accidentally interrupted the process.

I now want to resume the mirror with the following caveats:

- If wget has already downloaded a file, I don't want it downloaded 
  it again. I don't even want wget to check the timestamp: I know the 
  version I have is "recent enough".
- I *do* want wget to read the files it's already downloaded and 
  follow links inside those files.

I can use "-nc" for the first point above, but I can't seem to coerce 
wget to read through files it's already downloaded.

Things I've tried:

- The obvious "wget -c -m" doesn't work, because it wants 
  to compare timestamps, which requires making at least a HEAD request 
  to the remote server.
- "wget -nc -m" doesn't work, since -m implies -N, and -nc is 
  incompatible with -N.
- "wget -F -nc -r -l inf" is the best I could come up with, but it 
  still fails. I was hoping "-F" would coerce wget into reading local, 
  already-downloaded files as HTML, and thus follow links, but this 
  doesn't appear to happen.
- I tried a few other options (like "-c" and "-B [sitename]"), but 
  nothing works.

How do I get wget to resume this mirror?

Comment: Nope, but I wrote my own program to do this: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-wget-m80.pl

Comment: Killer, thanks. I don't understand how people got things done before SO/GH

Answer (score 14):

Apparently this works:

> Solved: Wget error “Can’t timestamp and not clobber old files at the
>   same time.” Posted on February 4, 2012 While trying to resume a
>   site-mirror operation I was running through Wget, I ran into the error
>   “Can’t timestamp and not clobber old files at the same time”. It turns
>   out that running Wget with the -N and -nc flags set at the same time
>   can’t happen, so if you want to resume a recursive download with
>   noclobber you have to disable -N. The -m attribute (for mirroring)
>   intrinsically sets the -N attribute, so you’ll have to switch from -m
>   to -r in order to use noclobber as well.

From: http://www.marathon-studios.com/blog/solved-wget-error-cant-timestamp-and-not-clobber-old-files-at-the-same-time/

Comment: This does not fulfill the 2nd requirement: "follow links inside already downloaded files"

Answer (score 8):

`-m`, according to the [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) is equivalent to this longer series of settings: `-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing`. Just use those settings instead of `-m`, and without `-N` (timestamping).

Now I'm not sure if there is a way to get wget to download urls from existing html files. There probably is a solution, I know it can take html files as inputs and scrape all the links in them. Perhaps you could use a bash command to concatenate all the html files together into one big file.

I solved this problem by just deleting all the html files, because I didn't mind only redownloading them. But this might not work for everyone's use case.